# How to test web service with jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and I am trying to use it for Rest API testing. I want to obtain a session key(or token) after identification.

How can I pass this key to the other tests so that I can use it as a header there?

Example of test :

1./identification

2./addCity

3./showListCities

I perefer code java because i use jmeter and java to implemente web interface.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Why don't you just google it first. There are plenty of answers. 1:http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/restAPIJMeter.html
2:http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where is the key or token located you need to extract it with:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor)

Once you extract it into a JMeter Variable you can use [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) in order to add the relevant header. You will need the HTTP Header Manager in any case in order to send at least `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`.

If you prefer Java code check out [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/), however I'm pretty much sure that GUI way will be much faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends on whether you are making a series of API calls within the same Thread Group or over different Thread Groups. While the RegEx Extractor mentioned above allows you to save parameters to variables, you have to remember Jmeter variables are local, not global. So if you want to intend to re-use the parameter in other Thread Groups, add a Beanshell Assertion and use "setProperty" to save your variable.